# How may I detect if the number of input is within the limit

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, user-input

I want to read three inputs and want to count them so that I can display a custom error message if the user inputs less than three or more than three. The code for the program I'm trying to write is here:

```
echo "Enter three names"
read name1 name2 name3
```

I want to validate these inputs so that the input is exactly three names, not less nor more.

Comment: What do you mean? If the user enters `a b c d`, that's `a` stored in `name1`, `b` stored in `name2` and `c d` stored in `name3`. If they enter `a\ b c d`, that's `a b` stored in `name1`, `c` stored in `name2`, `d` stored in `name3`. In either case that's still 3 names as you pass 3 variables.

Answer (score 3):

By reading three names at once, you can't check that that you actually got three names very easily, especially since names have a tendency to sometimes contains spaces.  You could detect getting *fewer* than three names by testing whether the variables are empty, but that's only solving half the problem.

Instead read each name separately:

```
echo 'Enter three names:' >&2
read -r -p 'Name 1: ' name1
read -r -p 'Name 2: ' name2
read -r -p 'Name 3: ' name3
```

This would prevent the user from entering too many names (as one is read per `read` call, and you only have three of these) and you would use

```
if [ -z "$name1" ] ||
   [ -z "$name2" ] ||
   [ -z "$name3" ]
then
    echo 'One or more names were empty!' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

or something similar to detect too few names entered.

Or, if you want the names in an array:

```
echo 'Enter three names:' >&2
for (( i=1; i<=3; ++i )); do
    read -r -p "Enter name $i: " name[i]
done
```

You could then either check `${name[i]}` directly after it was read, or do it later in a separate loop.

I would probably do something like

```
echo 'Enter three names:' >&2
for (( i=1; i<=3; ++i )); do
    if ! read -r -p "Enter name $i: " name[i] || [ -z "${name[i]}" ]
    then
        echo 'Invalid input, exiting' >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

This would treat end-of-file (the user pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>) or an empty entry as an error and exit.

Alternatively,

```
echo 'Enter three names:' >&2
for (( i=1; i<=3; ++i )); do
    while true; do
        if ! read -r -p "Enter name $i: " name[i]; then
            echo 'Ok, bye' >&2
            exit 1
        elif [ -n "${name[i]}" ]; then
            # string is non-empty (good!), skip to next name
            break
        fi
        echo 'Empty input, try again' >&2
    done
done
```

This would allow the user to terminate the script by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> and it would ask the user to enter the name again if the string entered was empty. This kind of input loop would also allow you to *verify the user's input* in other ways than just requiring that it was non-empty.